# How to give execute privilege to gradlew file before checking to git

Tags: gradle, gradlew, concourse

Can someone let me know how to give execute privilege to gradlew file so that the shell script inside concourse server can execute ./gradlew test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the `./gradlew` gets to the concourse container. If it is part of a `git` resource, which I assume is the most likely way you are using it, then you have to commit the permissions on your own machine and then push, as github picks up the permissions of every file on your local file system. So...

```
chmod +x gradlew
git add .
git ci -m "fix permissions for gradlew"
git push
```